# Selecting sub-sets using Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, subset

Say you need to pick a subset of N elements from a set S, where N << |S|, that makes the best combination according to some metrics you defined. I'd like to use Machine learning, and for every element of S, I can generate a feature vector that describes that element, and during training I can assign the upmentioned metrics as score to that feature vector.

A possible approach would be to create a (linear) regressor, assign a score to each element of S, and pick the top-K or those over a threshold, but this approach assumes that the selection of elements is independent (i.e. elements that are good individually are also good together), which is not my case.

Note that I may use a set of element-to-element features to describe the goodness of a chosen subset, but than it would be computationally inconvenient to try all possible subsets (which are 2^|S|).

Are you aware of any algorithm or approach to do that in a smarter way?

Comment: If `S_n` is your subset, what about the scoring function `f` that we apply on `S_n`. Do we have any information how `f` behaves? It seems that you do not want to make the `independence` assumption and you don't have to. But then you have to find features for the whole set `S_n` and avoid trying to calculate the overall score by applying some `f' ` to each element separately. This implicitly again assumes some kind of independence.

Comment: In my case, `f` is [F1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score), since I want to maximize precision and recall of my solution `S_n`. I may come up with a few features for the whole `S_n`, though they'd be weaker wrt individual elements' features. An idea that came to my mind was to add to `S_n`'s features the min/max/avg of each individual elements' features, but this approach did not give very good results.